# Can I refer an external Java project from Drools project in eclipse?

Tags: drools

While I try to import a Java class(myClass) from Project A in Eclipse to a drl file in Project B, im getting the error as "Error Importing: com.mycompany.myClass"

I have the Project A in the java build path of Project B

For Project A source folder is src/main/java.

Please help

Comment: They're just Java projects, so it's certainly possible. I do it all the time. However it may be worth clarifying what version of Drools you are using. Also, does the class you are importing have dependencies of its own, which are not on the classpath of Project B? Given Java class naming conventions, would I be correct in assuming that `myClass` is a typo in your question and should have been `MyClass`?

Comment: Im using Drools 6.0.1 and Jboss Studio 7.

Comment: Is project A defined as a dependency in the Maven pom.xml for project B?

Comment: build path is not necessarily the same as runtime classpath. Is Project A on the runtime classpath when you're running Project B?